# get index name within specific table name

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I need to check if this index not exist in specific table name not in all tables
because this select statement select all indexes under this condition.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name from sysindexes WHERE name = 'IDX_InsuranceID')

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_InsuranceID] ON [dbo].[QuoteInsurances] 
(
    [InsuranceID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your check is okay, I would change two things:

- use the `sys.indexes` system catalog view (if you're on SQL Server 2005 or newer) instead of the older, deprecated `sysindexes` system table
- add a check to the object_id (the link to the table) to your query

Something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'IDX_InsuranceID' 
               AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('your-table-name-here'))
   -- do whatever you need to do here.....
```

Comment: +1, but it's worth schema-scoping the OBJECT_ID check - i.e. OBJECT_ID('[schema-name].[table-name]')

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly no 2 indexes in the entire database can have the same name, so I think you're safe. If you think I'm incorrect, try to create two indexes on different tables with the same name and see what happens...

Comment: I think u aren't right because u can make two indexes under same name in the entire database one for each table. because of that i asked that question.

Comment: You are correct. I learned something today. What I was thinking of was constraints (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255(SQL.80).aspx). They are unique to the database, but index names are unique to the table. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258260(SQL.80).aspx)